# Spam socket io connections

Tags: node.js, sockets, spam

How to prevent if someone spam socket connection like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    io.connect('ws://localhost:9001');
}
```

I've googled but all of the topic is talking about how to prevent `emit` by rate limit and etc. But rate limit couldn't be used if someone spamming connections instead of spamming message. Any solution or hint for this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every websocket connection request's first step is HTTP GET handshake request, so you can limit number of requests on load-balancer/proxy server by IP. All requests  over the limit would be declined before reaching your application.
For example, read about how to do it with Nginx web proxy [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-http/).

If you can't or don't want to setup proxy server, you can do the same on application level with packages like [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) or [express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit).

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // rate limit here by IP or user ID
});
```